# Is there a more efficient way to find index of an element without using list built-in functions?

Tags: python, list, performance, indexing

We can get the index of an element in a list using the `.index()` function.
I was wondering if there's any more efficient way to find the index **without using the built-in function (of the list).**

Currently, I have written the following code using `enumerate`:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number to get the index:"))
l = [3,11,4,9,1,23,5]
if x in l: # I think this line is unnecessary and is increasing the time. 
    for i, val in enumerate(l):
        #Instead checking for x above can i use
        #if x == val: Don't worry about the indentation I'll fix it.   
        print(f"Index of {x} is {i}.")
else:
    print("Item not found.")
```

So, is there a more efficient way(in terms of time taken) to accomplish this?
**I want a more efficient implementation than the code I have written above and not in terms of `.index`**.

Comment: If there was an obvious, more efficient way, it would have been implemented by the Python people as part of `.index()`. Your question is a little weird to be honest.

Comment: We could always use a different data structure (e.g., dict). However are you also counting the cost to create the data structure?

Comment: @Keto Yes, i am counting for the data structure as well

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra algorithmically speaking yes, but in Python, using built-ins for these sorts of operations will invariably be faster than what you can code up by hand.

Comment: Well i am asking a faster implementation than the code written by me not `.index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### use [list comprehension](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension/) in python

```
l = [3, 11, 4, 9, 1, 23, 5, 11]
indexes = [index for index in range(len(l)) if l[index] == 11]
```

output:

```
[1, 7]
```

### use `numpy` for finding the matching indices.

```
import numpy as np

l = [3, 11, 4, 9, 1, 23, 5, 11]
np_array = np.array(l)
item_index = np.where(np_array == 11)
print (item_index)
```

### [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) is efficient:

```
import random
import time

import numpy as np

limit = 10 ** 7
l = [None] * limit
for i in range(limit):
    l[i] = random.randint(0, 1000000)

start = time.time()
np_array = np.array(l)
item_index = np.where(np_array == 11)
print('time taken by numpy', time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
for index, value in enumerate(l):
    if (value == 11):
        pass
print('time taken by enumerate',time.time() - start)
```

Output:

```
time taken by numpy 0.9375550746917725
time taken by enumerate 1.4508612155914307
```

### [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

```
import random
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread

import numpy as np

start = time.time()
limit = (10 ** 4)
l = [None] * limit
for i in range(limit):
    l[i] = random.randint(0, 1000000)


def testNumpy():
    np_array = np.array(l)
    for i in range(1000):
        value = random.randint(0, 1000000)
        item_index = np.where(np_array == value)


def testEnumerate():
    for i in range(1000):
        randValue = random.randint(0, 1000000)
        for index, value in enumerate(l):
            if (value == randValue):
                pass


def _testNumpy(repeat):
    import timeit
    s = """\
testNumpy()
    """
    print(timeit.timeit(stmt=s, setup="from __main__ import testNumpy", number=repeat, globals=globals()),
          end=":numpy\n")


def _testEnumerate(repeat):
    import timeit
    s = """\
testEnumerate()
        """
    print(timeit.timeit(stmt=s, setup="from __main__ import testEnumerate", number=repeat, globals=globals()),
          end=':enumerate\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    repeat = 10
    processes = [Process(target=_testNumpy, args=(repeat,)), Process(target=_testEnumerate, args=(repeat,))]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Output:

```
0.2232685430001311:numpy
8.573617108999997:enumerate
```

Comment: Can you also explain why will it be faster?

Comment: Because `numpy` is written in C and all of the looping and iteration happens in C, not Python. No GIL, no interpreter, just fast compiled code running on spatially local memory data.

Comment: Some comments about the code: (1) you don't actually return the index anywhere. Numpy would return a tuple containing an empty list, while the enumerate loop just breaks the loop without doing anything. This makes the comparison incorrect.

Comment: (2) Your timeit example contains some unused imports and variables. (3) The list creation could much more elegantly be done using list comprehension: `l = [random.randint(0, 1000000) for _ in range(limit)]`. (4) Why do you use multiprocessing for the benchmark? It makes the code more complicated and messes up the timing. For the benchmark to be correct, the tests should be performed in a single process without other disturbances.

Comment: (5) `testNumpy()` and `testEnumerate()` do not do the same thing. The numpy test searches random values (which do likely not occur in the array) while the enumerate test searches for the number 11. To do a fair comparison, both tests should search the same values in the same list. And you would have to make some assumptions about the realistic use cases. Are the values expected to be in the list or not? When searching random numbers, it is likely that the number you search is not in the list, which means that the whole list has to be searched.

Comment: Also note that the Python code works for any object (for example strings as well), while numpy only works with numbers.

Comment: By the way, I do agree with your statement that numpy is (much) faster. However, the prove/example is a bit messy and could be improved using above comments. Hope this helps. It would also be useful to add the explanation (provided by Silvio Mayolo) in your answer.